# Runing alphafold job in singularity

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, job-scheduling, singularity-container

I am new to singularity concept but successfully created singularity image for running alpha fold tool. I am encountering below-mentioned error.
I would like to request if anyone could explain how to troubleshoot the error or any related information that may help to combat it.
Thank you in advance.

**singularity run --nv alphafold220.sif --fasta_paths=/home/igib/AF_singualrity/test.fasta**

**

*> /sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't create temporary cache file

> /etc/ld.so.cache~: Read-only file system Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File "/app/alphafold/run_alphafold.py", line 37, in 
> from alphafold.model import data   File "/app/alphafold/alphafold/model/data.py", line 19, in 
> from alphafold.model import utils   File "/app/alphafold/alphafold/model/utils.py", line 22, in 
> import haiku as hk   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haiku/**init**.py", line 17,
> in 
> from haiku import data_structures   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haiku/data_structures.py",
> line 17, in 
> from haiku._src.data_structures import to_immutable_dict   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haiku/_src/data_structures.py",
> line 30, in 
> from haiku._src import utils   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haiku/_src/utils.py", line 24,
> in 
> import jax   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/**init**.py", line 108, in
>
> from .experimental.maps import soft_pmap   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/experimental/maps.py",
> line 25, in 
> from .. import numpy as jnp   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/numpy/**init**.py", line
> 16, in 
> from . import fft   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/numpy/fft.py", line 17, in
>
> from jax._src.numpy.fft import (   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/_src/numpy/fft.py", line
> 19, in 
> from jax import lax   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/lax/**init**.py", line
> 330, in 
> from jax._src.lax.fft import (   File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jax/_src/lax/fft.py", line
> 144, in 
> xla.backend_specific_translations['cpu'][fft_p] = pocketfft.pocketfft AttributeError: module 'jaxlib.pocketfft' has no
> attribute 'pocketfft'*

**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seeing same error. I believe I seen this error in another project due to an out of memory constraint or disk full.

Comment: Update-- maybe scratch found some reports it is related to GPU not detected or wrong driver/edition.  Still researching.

Comment: See this fix for another project may be relevant--https://github.com/saharmor/dalle-playground/pull/79/commits/ab386712c481587cd0de0c5f1553d66e913fc9c6

Answer (score 0):

Singularity images run on a read-only file system, with the exception being directories that have been mounted from the host OS.

You can enable a tmpfs overlay when running by using the `--writable-tmpfs` flag. Note that the max size of the tmpfs overlay is the size of `/dev/shm`, which can be smaller than expected in some cloud VMs.